# Conversion error in template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm having a problem with one of my functions within a template class.

`template <class T>

T complex<T>::returnMod()

    {

        T mod(0);

        mod = sqrt(pow(re,2.0) + pow(im,2.0));

        return mod;

    }`

I get the error: 'warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data' for the line in bold. How can I tell the compiler to use the type called for each class object? I create two different types of complex number, some with int and some with double. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are instantiating `complex` with type `int`, and the compiler is doing exactly what you asked for. `T` is int, and the expression `sqrt` returns a `double` so it has to convert.

I am not sure what you meant with *How can I tell the compiler to use the type called for each class object?*, but this is expected behavior.

Comment: That makes sense, I hadn't thought of sqrt returning a double when I tried making the function return an int type. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a casting:

```
mod = T(sqrt(pow(re,2.0) + pow(im,2.0)));
```

But this loses precision and rounds incorrectly (for example, it will convert `sqrt(3)` to `1`). You can solve the second problem but not the first one:

```
mod = T(0.5 + sqrt(pow(re,2.0) + pow(im,2.0)));
```

This will convert `sqrt(3)` to `2`.